# Custom attribute handling in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My goal is to serialize properties that don't have any attributes and properties which have a specific custom attribute.

For the following class:

```
public class Msg
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [CustomAttributeA]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [CustomAttributeB]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I call a method `Serialize(object, CustomAttributeA)`, I want to have the following output:

```
{
    "Id" : someId,
    "Text" : "some text"
}
```

And when I call `Serialize(object, CustomAttributeB)`, I want to have following:

```
{
    "Id" : someId,
    "Status" : "some status"
}
```

I have read that it's possible to achieve this by creating a custom `ContractResolver`, but in this case must I create two separate contract resolvers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need two separate resolvers to achieve your goal.  Just make the custom `ContractResolver` generic, where the type parameter represents the attribute you are looking for when serializing.

For example:

```
public class CustomResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver where T : Attribute
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName);
            if (pi != null)
            {
                // if the property has any attribute other than 
                // the specific one we are seeking, don't serialize it
                if (pi.GetCustomAttributes().Any() &&
                    pi.GetCustomAttribute<T>() == null)
                {
                    prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Then, you can make a helper method to create the resolver and serialize your object:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(object obj) where T : Attribute
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CustomResolver<T>(),
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
}
```

When you want to serialize, call the helper like this:

```
string json = Serialize<CustomAttributeA>(msg);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bRHbLy

Comment: You could also make this generic - IMO a little neater `Serialize<CustomTypeA>(obj)` and `Serialize<CustomTypeB>(obj);`

Comment: Great answer BTW!